# If prepared SQL has a quoted text - does it force a re-compilation of the statement?

Tags: sql, prepared-statement

SQL #1:
SELECT SLIB_DIFF(COLA,COLB,'MM/DD/YY') FROM T101 WHERE OBJ_ID=?

SQL #2:
SELECT SLIB_DIFF(COLA,COLB,?) FROM T101 WHERE OBJ_ID=?

A custom function SLIB_DIFF takes last parameter as a quoted date format and it will not change.
Does it make sense to make this text into a bound parameter?
The only thing changing in the query is OBJ_ID.
Will database server re-compile this on every execution (because it 'sees' the quoted text)?

In short, is query #2 faster than query #1?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why using string literals in a query would affect re-compilation or performance at all.

If I'm right in guessing you use MS SQL, you could check this for yourself by looking at `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`'s `execution_count` for your query after running it a few times. Other DBMSes have similar facilities.